# Writing a view to fetch user data and add it to the database

Tags: django, django-views

I make a project which generates a random book when the user press a button. The view that does that is:

```
def random_book(request):
    cartile=Books.objects.all()
    random_item=random.choice(cartile)
    return render(request, 'carti/book.html', context={"random_item": random_item})
```

On the page were you are redirected to see the generated random book I want to add a button that says "add to read later".

I know how to make a manyotmany relationship between profile model and books model, but I have no idea how to write a view that gets the generated random book, adds it to the profile view_later field in the database, delete it with another button, what html tag and what should I write inside for "add  to read later" and the delete button.

Some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that depends on the flow of you website.

If I interpret your idea correctly, one simple way would be to have a view that takes the id of the selected book and add it to read later collection (in the case of the add).

Doing a lot of suppositions, something like this should do the basic,

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('site/read_later_add<int:book_pk>/', views.read_later_add),
]

# View (in site/views.py)
def read_later_add(request, book_pk=1):
    # get user profile
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    # get the book
    book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_pk)
    # add book to view_later collection
    profile.view_later.add(book) # <- this is it
    # give some success message
    return render(request, 'read_later_add_success.html')
```

The remove case would be similar just using `profile.view_later.remove(book)`.

BTW, I did not add any error handling or checks, you should definitely should dot that.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly. You can get the random book by implementing a function that return a random number between 1 and the size of *Books* column. And pass the return integer of this random function to Books.objects.get(pk=random_int)